# How to get EditText value from xml in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

What I've tried so far:

getString(R.id.editBrand) => this returns false (R.id.editBrand returns a long number)

view.findViewById(R.id.editBrand) => runs to nullreference

Any help would be vm appreciated, thank you!

My whole fragment:

```
class CreateFragment : Fragment() {

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentCreateBinding>(inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_create,container,false)
        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dataSource = CarDatabase.getInstance(application).carDatabaseDao
        val viewModelFactory = CarViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)

        val carViewmodel =
                ViewModelProvider(
                        this, viewModelFactory).get(CarViewmodel::class.java)
        val adapter = CarAdapter()


        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener { view : View ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_createFragment_to_readFragment)

            carViewmodel.onCreated(12, view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editBrand).editBrand.toString(), "blue")
        }
    
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood your question right, all you have to do is: `val value = binding.editBrand.text`

Comment: ty so much!!! I spent an hour on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
binding.editBrand.text.toString()
```

Since `binding` is the reference to your layout here.

If you use `view.findViewById<EditText>`, `view` refers to the `submitButton` and calling findViewById on it will look for child views.

`getString()` take a string resource as a parameter and not a view resource.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. Sadly I get unresolved reference to findViewById after binding. val value = binding.editBrand.text works perfectly tho

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks for notifying